# Unicode issue with insert ZERO WIDTH SPACE into database

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, unicode

I am using CKEditor and it seems that it is possible with the correct keypresses to get the following unicode character inserted into the textarea.

> U+200B    ​   \xe2\x80\x8b    ZERO WIDTH SPACE

Now when I try to save this into a MySQL database I get the following error:-

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8B </...' for column 'Content' at row 1
```

From what I can see I have a several options:-

1. Change the collation on my table, however I am not entirely sure what impact this will have on my c# MVC4 application that uses NHibernate as the ORM
2. Strip out the unicode from the string before I insert into the database, however I am not entirely how to do this and even if it is correct.
3. This seems to be a bug in CKEditor for certain browsers, however I would like to future proof myself by not waiting for a fix.

So my question is simply what is my best option to get around this issue?

[image: Table structure]

Comment: Have you tried changing the charset of the column to `utf8`?

Comment: Not yet, I would like to know what impact this might have (if any), the content is going to be an email that will be sent out.

Comment: If it's going to be an email then you may need to try sending some unicode and test it in different browsers and email clients.  I'm familiar with unicode in emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibly your `charset` is Latin1.

You shouldn't try to store unicode data in Latin1 column. You will probably have to change that:

```
ALTER TABLE campaignemail MODIFY Content LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Beware when doing so that if you erroneously stored "unicode-pretending-to-be-latin1" this might put a mess in your table values.

---

BTW the `charset` is the encoding used to map from a "letter" (strictly speaking: a codepoint) to "bytes".

The `collation` define the relative order between the various "letters". If is used to search/sort columns.

Comment: Do you know if this will have an impact I use the `content` column as the body of an email?